# Physical bitcoin vs. Paper wallet?

Tags: wallet, security, paper-wallet, wallet-security, physical-coins

What is the main difference between a **Physical bitcoin** and  **Paper wallet** ?

And which one is more secure ? And why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A physical bitcoin is simply a metal or plastic coin-shaped object, usually with a private key embedded aside. It is functionally identical to a paper wallet.

Both are only as secure as their storage medium, and passphrase, if one was set during creation.

Answer (score 2):

A paper wallet is more secure than a physical coin with addresses, as the former you can make yourself, on your own machine, while with a physical bitcoin you never know under what conditions it was manufactured and who could have copied the keys.